# Activate code when loop reaches a certain number

Tags: python

I need to know how to run code when the for loop reaches a certain number. The loop currently runs

```
card_a(stack1_xpos, stack1_ypos)
```

the number of times found in the third value of the list shown below (It is 9 in this example)

```
['Stack 1', 'Suit A', 9, 6]
```

My current function is:

```
def deal_cards(game):
for (idx, stack) in enumerate(game):         
    if stack[0] == 'Stack 1':                       
        if stack[1] == 'Suit A':                    
            for i in range(stack[2]):                                 
                card_a(stack1_xpos, stack1_ypos)
```

I want it so that when the loop reaches the same number as the 4th item in the list (6 in this example) it will run the code:

```
card_e(stack1_xpos, stack1_ypos)
```

And then return back to running

```
card_a(stack1_xpos, stack1_ypos)
```

for the rest of the loop.

How could I do this?

Comment: `if i == stack[3]: card_e(...)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm interpreting your question correctly, then the answer is straightforward:

```
for i in range(stack[2]):
    if i == stack[3]:
        card_e(stack1_xpos, stack1_ypos)
    card_a(stack1_xpos, stack1_ypos)
```